# Using SWIG to create a Python wrapper on Linux

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I created a swig wrapper c++ to python. I have install both files (python and .so file) but when I import my python file, this error occours:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/root/test", line 1, in <module>     import Systemtechnik.libsysproject   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/Systemtechnik/libsysproject.py", line 13, in <module>     from . import _libsysproject ImportError: cannot import name '_libsysproject' from 'Systemtechnik' (unknown location)
```

I have copied the .so file to different places but nothing helped.
I have found nothing in the forum.
chatGPz has no helpful info either.

this is the makefile:

```
APP = libsysproject

LIBSOURCES=*.cpp
OUTS = *.o
NAME := sysproject
MAJOR = 1.0
MINOR = 1
VERSION = $(MAJOR).$(MINOR)
 
all: lib$(NAME).so
 
lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION): compile
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OUTS) -shared -Wl,-soname,_lib$(NAME).so.$(MAJOR) -o _lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION)
 
lib$(NAME).so: lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION)
    rm -f _lib$(NAME).so.$(MAJOR) _lib$(NAME).so
    ln -s _lib$(NAME).so.$(VERSION) _lib$(NAME).so.$(MAJOR)
    ln -s _lib$(NAME).so.$(MAJOR) _lib$(NAME).so
 
compile: swig
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -fPIC libsysproject.cpp libsysproject_wrap.cxx -Irecipe-sysroot/usr/include/python3.9
 
swig:
    swig -c++ -python -py3 libsysproject.i
 
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.so *.so.*
```

the whole build is with petalinux/yocto.

Comment: Did you copy all symbolic links too? Post `ls -al /usr/lib/python3.9/Systemtechnik/`

Comment: yes. but is was in the wrong directory. I solved it